# Xslt: Embedding an image in a RSS feed

Tags: xslt, rss

I am using Umbraco and I need to display an image in a Rss Feed. The feed is generated by **Xslt**.

Everything works if I do text stuff. Such stuff is technically feasible, but the feed I analyzed had been generated by WordPress.

The challenge is that I have no idea how I can embed  within my  tag.

I have a variable, say "url", that returns the full url of the underlying image. How can I insert  within ? Remember I am using Xslt to achieve the task.

```
<content:encoded>          
  <img src="{$url}" />
</content:encoded>
```

I guess that CDATA must be used, but I am not able to escape correctly illegal characters :(

Thanks for your help.

Roland

Comment: Why would you want to embed an image in an RSS feed?

Comment: You can output "encode HTML" with standar XSLT just ussing character entities.

Comment: what is the problem? WHy can't you produce with XSLT normal (unescaped) markup? Please, explain in your question.

Comment: Here is the solution I found: <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;![CDATA[&lt;img src=&quot;', concat($siteUrl, photo),'&quot;/&gt;',']]&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> This is crazy to read, I know. @Alejandro and @Dimitri: the image I have to embed must be enclosed within <content:encode/> That's why I did CDATA stuff

Comment: <content:encoded/> accept only a single <value-of /> Everything must be enclosed within select with tons of markup that must escaped :s Actually escaping the illegal characters was what I wasn't able to do :p That's why I posted here. Thanks for taking the time to read my post guys I really appreciate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

roland, you're trying to escape things twice. It's unnecessary (not to mention hideous!) [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/RSS/Article/Why_RSS_Content_Module_is_Popular_-_Including_HTML_Contents) shows:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[This is <i>italics</i>.]]></content:encoded>
```

I.e. they're just escaping the markup inside the `<content:encoded>` once, and they use CDATA to do that. In your case, CDATA is awkward because you need to substitute $url in the middle. So you could use two CDATA sections wrapped around an `<xsl:value-of select="$url" />`: (indented for clarity)

```
<content:encoded>
  <![CDATA[<img src="]]>
  <xsl:value-of select='$url' />
  <![CDATA[">]]>
</content:encoded>
```

But that would be needlessly verbose. The second CDATA section is unneeded. And we can do better while using the same principle: escape the markup characters (once) that would cause the string to be parsed into a tree. In your case, only the initial `<` needs to be escaped. You can use `&lt;` instead of CDATA to escape the `<`. Put this in your XSLT:

```
<content:encoded>&lt;img src="<xsl:value-of select='$url' />"></content:encoded>
```

The `<xsl:value-of>` is not really inside quotes, from XSLT's perspective... those quotes are just the content of text nodes. The `<xsl:value-of>` works as a normal XSLT instruction.

Change `select='$url'` to `select="concat($siteUrl, photo)"` if that's what you need. (I.e. photo is a child element of the context node, and its text value is the name of the image file.)

Comment: Thanks Lars, it works like a charm ;) At least the first solution where the <xsl:value-of /> is embedded within 2 CDATA. I did it this night :o I was not able to make the second solution work: An error message pops up whenever I want to save the document. I guess there is an illegal character that wasn't escaped rightly. I love the solution wrapping <xsl:value-of /> into 2 CDATA.IT is yet verbose, but meaningful to me :D Thanks a lot for all your posts guys ;)

Comment: @roland, glad it worked for you. What error did you get when you tried to save the doc? Very strange...

Comment: Hi Lars, both solutions work perfectly :s I probably made the copy and paste too quickly. I wish I were more rigorous. Anyway thanks a lot for your help guys, you rock! ;)